# AnyLogic - Defining a network of agents with different rules of connection

Tags: networking, anylogic, agent

I am new to AnyLogic and I would appreciate it if you could guide me. I have 100 doctors and 30 surgeons. Each doctor is connected to a number of surgeons, and there is no general rule for their connection. For example, one doctor may be connected to 5 surgeons, another doctor may be connected to only one surgeon, and so on. Now I want to define their network of connections in the software. The data is in Excel. The first column contains the codes for the doctors and the second column contains the codes for the surgeons. For example, if doctor 1 is connected to surgeon 20 and surgeon 30, then doctor 1 is written in the first row and surgeon 20 is written in the column next to it. In the second row, doctor 1 is written again and in front of it is surgeon 30.

I don't know what should I do

Comment: You need to clarify the following: 1) what do you mean by "connected"? 2) show how the excel table look like, 3) how are the codes in excel related to something in AnyLogic?... make your best to clarify all this if you want to maximize the chances to get your question answered

Comment: Hi, this place works best for you if you ask very specific questions, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. Your question is far too broad and would need a full lecture to tell you all about it. I suggest you read up here to learn how to ask great questions: Use https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and this article focused on AnyLogic: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow . Treat us as very busy colleagues that are happy to help. The more effort you put into your question, the more likely you will get a reply :)